# VBA Excel How to hide and unhide tabs on ribbon with password protection?

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding a sheet in Excel 2007 (with a password) OR hide VBA code in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043468/hiding-a-sheet-in-excel-2007-with-a-password-or-hide-vba-code-in-excel)

I have set of excel sheets with macros. Now i want to hide the tabs like **Review** and **Developer** so that users can't do modifications to the code. I know that **File->Options->Customize Ribbon->Select Tab->Enable\Disable->Click Ok** hides the tabs but any user can unhide the tabs with the same process. So i want an alternative way to restrict users to unhide Tabs which are hidden.

Comment: [Post1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259897/how-password-protection-of-excel-vba-code-works). [Post2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259663/vba-password-protection-how-it-works-is-it-secure-are-there-any-alternatives?rq=1) and if you notice to your right hand side the `related` posts there are a tons of them. Frankly when you were posting this, wish you could check on those ;)

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043468/hiding-a-sheet-in-excel-2007-with-a-password-or-hide-vba-code-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Am, it would be better to protect the VBA files directly, so a user needs a password to modify them. This should be found in the left-hand properties menu in the VBA-Editor